# CORS issue using OData service

Tags: cors, odata, sapui5, xsodata

I have created an `OData` service using `SAP's XS` application. The service is working perfectly when I try to access it via browser. When I try to consume it via `SAPUI5` application, it gives me `CORS` error.

I even enabled the cors in the `.xsaces`s file but it still gives me access-control-allow-origin flag error.

I am making use of the trial account and my XS application contains only the `OData` file i.e.`myOdata.xsodata` file.

Could anyone please point me to what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of "destinations" in the Hana Cloud Platform. That acts as a proxy.

Although, as per my knowledge, currently odata services via xs application cannot be configured via destinations in **trial account**. Hence, you would also need to setup cloud connector and register your service in it. Then configure the destination as on-premise to your localhost running odata service.

Answer (score 0):

the response should contain the access-control-allow-origin flag with the the URI of your application.